# Virtual COM Port fails to create when installing drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, com-port

So here is my situation. I'm working with a Matrix Orbital OK204-25 USB Display, [Display DocS](https://www.matrixorbital.com/ok204-25). Part of the installation requires me to install the displays drivers. During the process the drivers are suppose to install in two phases.

The first phase, after pointing the device in device manager to the drivers installs the relevant drivers for the Display itself. The second phase, which I'm suppose to get a prompt for after the first phase complete, is suppose to create a Virtual COM port for the display and show up under Ports.

Now, the drivers I'm using installed and configured properly on one machine. However, the second PC I'm attempting to install the drivers on doesn't create the VCP.

Is there any settings that are within Windows 10, that I should be looking at that would prevent device drivers from creating a VCP as part of the installation process of installing the drivers?

Comment: Try to install while booting in Safe mode. Perhaps some third-party software is interfering.

Comment: that did the trick thank you. However, it didn't actually create the VCP in a single driver installation. I had to install it once, and then update the drivers again, during the second attempt it created the VCP correctly. I tried the 2 step outside of safe mode and it failed to work. But safe mode was the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing while
[booting in Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)
helps in fixing installation problems for many cases.

For the poster, this was the first step in fixing his problem.
The second step was updating the drivers again.